# Changing values of animation between its iterations

Tags: java, animation, javafx, 3d

I'm trying to change the parameters of rotation animation(x, y, z and vv) using the animation timer handle (long now) method, but I don't know how to redirect the values with each iteration.

I've tried placing constructors there:

```
Cylinder cyli = new Cylinder(200,40);        
Translate trans3 = new Translate(0, 0, 0);        
cyli.getTransforms().add(trans3);
cyli.setMaterial(pm);
cyli.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);

Group group = new Group();
group.setTranslateX(150);
group.setTranslateY(150);
group.setTranslateZ(100);
rotate = new Rotate(0, axis);
group.getTransforms().setAll(rotate);

group.getChildren().add(cyli);

center.getChildren().add(group);

final Timeline rotationAnimation = new Timeline();
rotationAnimation.setCycleCount(1);

timer = new AnimationTimer() {
    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        axis = new Point3D(x, y, z);
        rotate = new Rotate(0, axis);

        speed = 1/vv; 
        duration = Duration.seconds(speed);         
        //x, y, z and vv are values set by the user (variables)
    }
};

duration = Duration.seconds(speed);

KeyValue keyValue1 = new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(),360);
KeyFrame keyFrame1 = new KeyFrame(duration, keyValue1);

rotationAnimation.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame1);

rotationAnimation.play();
timer.start();
```

I wanted to change the x, y, z and vv values during or between the animations, these values are ment to be changed at any given time,but they stay the same. I come to thinking that i would somehow need to move the whole group to the handle method, but I have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: At the time `handle` is invoked the values have already been retrieved and even if they were not: You seem to overwrite the fields with equal values over and over again... Perhaps describing the desired effect would make this question answerable.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry if i didn't clarify this enough, hopefully now it's much more answerable. The x, y and z are the coordinates of the axis of rotation and vv (and rather speed value) is the duration of animation (basically how fast it spins) and I want these values to be overridden every time they change: user changes value of the slider -> parameters of rotation and animation are changed -> the cylinder moves around a different axis and/or at different speed